# Matching matrix in perl or bash

Tags: bash, perl, matrix, match

I was wondering if you could give me a hand to find a solution (not necesseraly giving me a code) to my problem.
I would like to create a "matching matrix" in perl or Bash.

Basically, my first file is an extracted list of IDs, not unique (file1)

```
ID1 
ID4 
ID20 
ID1
```

For making my life easier my second file is just a long line with multiples IDs (file2)

> ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 .... IDn

I would like to achieve this output:

```
    ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7 .... ID20 IDn
ID1  X
ID4              X
ID20                                  X
ID1  X
```

The tricky part for me is to add the "X" when a match is found.

Any help, hint is more than appreciated.

Comment: `The tricky part for me is...` Could you post a code for not so tricky part? So we can concentrate on specific problems without having to implement everything from scratch.

Comment: Isn't this almost trivial? Just keep both lists in an array, print a header, then create a nested loop over both arrays and print X when the keys match.

Comment: So @TLP did what you asked for -- `give me a hand`.  Now answer your own question and earn the [Self-Learner](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) badge!

Comment: Thank you TLP. I am working on it. Do not know why I was storing file2 into an hash. I'll try with the array now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer for this issue:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open(FILE1, "file1") || die "cannot find file1";
open(FILE2, "file2") || die "cannot find file2";

#read file2 to create hash
my $file2 = <FILE2>;
$file2 =~ s/\n//;
my @ids = split(/\s+/, $file2);
my %hash;
my $i = 1;
map {$hash{$_} = $i++;} @ids;

#print the first line
printf "%6s",'';
for my $id (@ids) {
    printf "%6s", $id;
}
print "\n";

#print the other lines
while(<FILE1>) {
    chomp;
    my $id = $_;
    printf "%6s", $id;
    my $index = $hash{$id};
    if ($index) {
        $index = 6 * $index;
        printf "%${index}s\n",'x';
    } else {
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You have fallen into the trap of using `||` along with no parentheses for `open`. Your `die` statement can never happen. Read the precedence list in `perldoc perlop` and you will see why. You are also splitting on a single space, when you probably meant to split on `' '`, to avoid creating empty fields on consecutive spaces.

Comment: The only difference between `' '` and `/\s+/` in split is that the former does what you think and strips leading whitespace. So you almost always want that. And if you want a named variable in a while loop, just do `while (my $id = <FILE1>)`.. and of course, you should always use three argument open and lexical file handles.